# Access Denied when I change password in AD from Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

Here is the code:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com", "DC=domain,DC=com", "login", "password");
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
user.SetPassword(newPass);
```

For localhost deployment it works well, but when I try to run this code in Azure Web App I am getting the following error

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
```

What's wrong with it? How can I reset user password in AD from Azure Web App?

Comment: This is pretty old but have you found an answer? Im running into a similar issue.

Comment: @EdBoykin using VPN solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be the issue if you did not use Virtual Network for Web App and local domain to merge them into the one network. [Tutorial](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/04/06/step-by-step-connect-an-azure-web-app-to-an-existing-virtual-network/). That will put your resources into the one VPN and the issue should go away.

Comment: I forgot to write that I am using VPN and everything is working properly in AD. Only SetPassword is causing the error.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев ok, good. Try to use ChangePassword instead of SetPassword? And see [that](https://consultrikin.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/ad-change-password-c-access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e_accessdenied/) - may be helpful.

Comment: ChangePassword is not what I need. The old password isn't known to the administrator. I'll try to make the link instructions